# Can I use LaTeX in a fictional code-weaving?

Tags: software-documentation, latex, microsoft-word

I'm working on a magic system that works with weaving types of power. The most commonly used power source is a magical code. I'm trying to base this code off of [latex](/questions/tagged/latex). LaTeX is a math code that is based on TeX. It's useful because it allows complex equations and all sorts of symbols, arrows, etc.

I'm wondering: if I'm going to use LaTeX (pronounced: *Lay-tech*) for my base and want to be able to insert these symbols into my writing by using the code in my actual drafts (not as a base for all of my writing, but as a base for when I want to insert "magical" symbols), what writing platform could I use that accepts both regular writing (fonts, bold, italicize, good for 200-page documents) and the LaTeX math code?

I experimented and found that three symbols: Alt+= allow LaTeX symbols in an equation in Word. However, I have the problem of fonts. I was interested in the \mathbb font in particular, especially with the effect it gives to letters. Does anyone have a solution to getting a LaTeX font in Word?

Comment: In a nutshell, I understand the question is "Can I publish fiction in LaTeX format?"

Comment: I think you should ask this question on [Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). We're really not experts on getting (La)TeX to work with other software.

Comment: I use Latex frequently for academic papers. Latex is perfectly capable of using other fonts; go to the TEX SE forum to figure out how, or read a manual. That said, if you intend to SELL your work, publishers will probably not even read your work if it is not in a standard font on plain paper with the correct wide margins and double spacing. They just don't, they are only interested in the story and reading it FAST, and whatever effect you love about the font, they will see that as too amateurish and difficult to read to bother with. Just a heads up, Anon.

Comment: I'm not sure enough that this is off topic that I'm going to mod-hammer it shut, but I'm far from certain that it's on topic either. Besides, if you're mostly interested in something resembling the `\mathbb{}` style characters, there's not necessarily any need to invoke LaTeX. With the caveat of @Amadeus' comment above, look at the Unicode "Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols" block, particularly those starting at U+1D538.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...what writing platform could I use that accepts both regular writing (fonts, bold, italicize, good for 200-page documents) and the LaTeX math code?

Many LaTeX editors support "regular writing". I use [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/) myself. Things like bold, italics etc. require LaTeX code, but most software packages like TeXstudio give you nice buttons and hot-keys to make the migration easier.

> Does anyone have a solution to getting a LaTeX font in Word?

It looks like your question has been asked before over on [TeX.SE - How to use LaTeX in Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111130/how-to-use-latex-in-word). From one of the answers there, it seems that it may be possible to run some LaTeX code in Word 2016.

You will likely find the support on Word is insufficient. If so, consider rendering your LaTeX code and then import clippings into Word as images. You will have to do something similar if you intend to publish to epub or mobi anyway.

If you want to publish to pdf or send your copy to a typesetter for printing, you will find you have greater flexibility by migrating your copy from Word to a LaTeX editor.

If you're dealing with a publisher, they may not want to deal with the cost and difficulties of incorporating your symbols. That is a conversation I would suggest you have with them early on in the process.

Answer (score 2):

ReStructuredText is a lightweight markup language with built in support for LaTeX math expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793190/latex-in-rst-processed-with-pandoc

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/Download), which I use to write novels. I feel it has advantages even if one doesn't want to include LaTeX formulae. For example, chapters are numbered automatically, and you can hide content in LyX notes and LaTeX comments, so your novel document can also contain private notes to yourself and old text you're removing but might want to use again later.